# linq to sql under the hood: why can't i query a date/time range less than 48 hours using linq to sql?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I don't understand a linq-to-sql error that seems to involve how linq to sql works 'under the hood'.

I have a linq to sql query looking for values within a date range. All of the fields queried have no null values in the underlying DB. If the start date and the end date are less than 48 hours apart, the query returns an error, *nullable object must have a value*.

```
Dim startDate As Date = New Date(2013, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1)
Dim endDate As Date = New Date(2013, 1, 6, 23, 59, 59) //date interval less than 48 hours
Dim count As Integer = (From l In myDB.myTable Where l.LabName = labToCheck And l.SuccessfulImport = True And l.DateProcessed > startDate And l.DateProcessed < endDate Select l.Epi).Sum //Nullable object must have a value.
```

On the other hand, when the dates are more than 48 hours apart (in the example below, the second line is different), it does not throw an error:

```
Dim startDate As Date = New Date(2013, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1)
Dim endDate As Date = New Date(2013, 1, 7, 23, 59, 59) //date interval more than 48 hours
Dim count As Integer = (From l In myDB.myTable Where l.LabName = labToCheck And l.SuccessfulImport = True And l.DateProcessed > startDate And l.DateProcessed < endDate Select l.Epi).Sum
```

What's going on? Does LINQ to SQL ignore time values? Are all datetimes in a DB on 1/5/2013 equivalent regardless of the time value associated? That is my interpretation of this error, because if linq to sql ignores time values than there would be no possible values greater than 1/5/13 and less than 1/6/13, hence generating the message: nullable object must have an error.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you have data in the range 5th Jan 2013 to 6th Jan 2013? That would explain the error.

Comment: yeah. we have data processed around 10:19 am on both of those dates

Comment: I can't see nullable object in code. Where is nullable object in your code? I think `DateProcessed` is nullable but hasn't value.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - My assumption would be that `(From l In myDB.myTable Where l.LabName = labToCheck And l.SuccessfulImport = True And l.DateProcessed > startDate And l.DateProcessed < endDate Select l.Epi)` returns null

Comment: How it can return `null` it is linq and returns enumrable.

Comment: If l.DateProcessed is a DateTime2 sql type then you need to change it to l.DateProcessed.Value

Comment: If you do "Count" in place of "Sum", does it error out? If not, what's the returned value?

Comment: You could try using LINQPad, which translates a LINQ query to SQL, to see what's going on: http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: @500-InternalServerError when i use sum instead of count I get 0 and it does not error out. I think you are on to something. I think that when it is erroring out,  the query returns no rows, so linq can't sum them (returning the error).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that was it. If you write up an answer, I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: @akh2103 I was just asking the question. Wasn't your expectation that there should have been data in that interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, that sum just doesnt work if you have no integer values. sum can be used without problems on integer arrays or if you pass in an anonymous function that resolves the property that should then be an integer.

furthermore it makes no sense to sum the result.

.sum is for summing all integers in an array, whereas count just counts all the items in the array.